# sqlalchemy concatenate columns dynamically

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to create a scalar by concatenating multiple columns. If the list of columns were static I could do:

```
sa.select([table.c.col1 + table.c.col2 + 'done']).as_scalar()
```

But, my list is dynamic. Is there a way to do this without using `eval()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost never need `eval()` — it can be [evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice). In this case just use `functools.reduce()` on your list of columns / expressions:

```
sa.select([reduce(operator.add, [table.c.col1, table.c.col2, 'done'])])
```